# Remmina will not start / open, even after reboot

Tags: bug-reporting, remmina, 15.10

I am really struggling here to understand what is going on with this.

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop, I use Remmina for VNC/RDP connections. It has always just worked.

I tried to open it now but the interface just does not open. Tried to reboot but still will not open.

Googling this does not help and I do not see any other issues like this. On launchpad there are 2 bugs with the same description but for 11.10 and 12.04. None provide a solution.

Does anyone know how I could diagnose this issue or get Remmina to open the interface again?

Comment: Please run Remmina from a terminal and paste its output into your question. Maybe this will uncover something helpful.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Well it is working right now and I need to use Remmina however when I have a chance I will try to reproduce this issue and do as requested, thanks for your support! :)

Comment: @DavidFoerster, revisiting this now and all I get back is a segmentation fault.

Comment: Since you seem to have solved the original issue already at some point you should open a new question for you new issue. Also, segmentation faults should probably reported as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the relative bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/753520

Changing the keyboard layout from ZA to US resolves the issue and enables the launch of Remmina.